# What is "Pending Activities" in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a memory leak in my web app.

When recording a heap snapshot, a sizable group is called "Pending Activities", and it seems to hold references to a lot of objects that should not be referenced from anywhere.

Searching online netted nothing.

What is this "Pending Activities" group, and can it be related to my leak?

Comment: [Poking the source](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q="::HasPendingActivity()"&m=100&type=cs) (see V8EmbedderGraphBuilder::VisitPendingActivities) seems to indicate these are things (mostly DOM or DOM API) not retained by references but by an unfinished activity e.g. a network fetch that's still connecting/transferring, IndexedDB transactions, worker stuff, media stuff, etc. You can try asking a chromium developer on their IRC or somewhere like [chromium-dev](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-dev) group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Chrome would not clear DOM memory during JS execution even if it's eligible to be collected; yielding during my execution with `requestAnimationFrame` allowed Chrome to clear the memory in-between.

Comment: hi. What does it mean "yielding during my execution with..."? Thanks

Comment: @superjos it means stopping your computation and continuing it in a later time, for instance with `requestAnimationFrame`. The browser has time to garbage-collect in-between.

Comment: thanks for reply, even on such an old thread. Now I got it.