# Understanding heap snapshot in chrome - pending activites, internal node

Tags: google-chrome, heap-memory, snapshot

I am trying to understand heap snapshots in Chrome. I am debugging memory leaks in my javascript application and was able to find out that most of the retained memory is used by Internal Node -> Pending activities -> C++ roots. What does it mean?

[image]

My application uses [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) for recording canvas and even though it is more complex the recording can be simplified like this:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const stream = canvas.captureStream(1)
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
mediaRecorder.addEventlistener('dataavailable', processEvent())
mediaRecorder.start()

// later in the code
mediaRecorder.stop()
mediaRecorder.stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop())
```

I believe I work with MediaRecorder API correctly and close the recorder and even stream right. Does anyone know what can cause these objects still be kept in memory?

Similar question:

- [What is "Pending Activities" in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121986/what-is-pending-activities-in-chrome)

Might be related to this chrome bug:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=899722